# App Not Responding while SQLite Database execSQL()

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a problem with Inserting my Values into my SQLite Database. I don't see an error in the Monitor(Logcat). When I click on the button to insert the data, then, the app just freezes.

Here is how I open the database:

```
newdb = openOrCreateDatabase("Count_DB",MODE_PRIVATE,null);
newdb.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Count(Name VARCHAR(50),Description VARCHAR(200),NoC VARCHAR(1000),Time VARCHAR(100));");
```

Here is the `onClick` event where I am saving the data:

```
cr.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                Vibrator n = (Vibrator)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                n.vibrate(500);
                DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss");
                Date now = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
                cDT = df.format(now);
                customD = new Dialog(nCounter.this);
                customD.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
                DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
                int width = metrics.widthPixels;
                //int height = metrics.heightPixels;
                customD.getWindow().setLayout((6 * width)/7, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                customD.setTitle("Save Counter");
                Button s = (Button)customD.findViewById(R.id.button);
                s.setText(Integer.toString(x));
                e1 = (EditText)customD.findViewById(R.id.editText);
                e2 = (EditText)customD.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
                save = (Button)customD.findViewById(R.id.button3);
                cancel = (Button)customD.findViewById(R.id.button2);
                save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View vv) {
                        name = e1.getText().toString();
                        desc = e2.getText().toString();
                        if (!name.equals("") && !desc.equals("")){
                            InsertintoCount();
                            while(true){
                                Snackbar.make(vv, "Countings Saved!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please fill in the fields!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                    }
                });
                cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        customD.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                customD.show();
                return true;
            }
        });
```

This is `InsertintoCount()` Method:

```
public boolean InsertintoCount(){
    String sqlc = "INSERT INTO Count VALUES('"+name+"','"+desc+"','"+x+"','"+cDT+"');";
    newdb.execSQL(sqlc);
    while(true){
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure you can use `Count` as a table name.

Comment: before i used "countings", still the problem persists... so i just tried a different name...

Comment: Remove all `while(true)`... Never do that without a good reason

Comment: A potentially harmful name. `Count()` is the name of a SQL function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an infinite loop running inside the `onClick` event. No doubt your app doesn't respond.

Remove this while loop :

```
while(true){
Snackbar.make(vv, "Countings Saved!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: Yeah! When I removed the while loop, the freezing got stopped but when i checked, the values are not getting inserted into the database

Comment: @AlokNaushad Try changing your table name. `Count` is already defined as a method name.

Comment: When I changed the Table name, when I added the value for the first time, it gets added but the second time I add a value, it doesn't show up... why???

Comment: @AlokNaushad How are you checking whether they are inserted or not?

Comment: I use a button in my main view...:                    mnew.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SQLiteDatabase mydatabase = openOrCreateDatabase("Count_DB",MODE_PRIVATE,null);
                Cursor resultSet = mydatabase.rawQuery("Select * from Countss",null);
                resultSet.moveToFirst();
                String name = resultSet.getString(0);
                String desc = resultSet.getString(1);
                Snackbar.make(v, "Name:"+name+" Desc:"+desc, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: @AlokNaushad This code will only show one record. I think your table is being updated. Loop through the cursor to see all the entries. Also as your original question is answered, I suggest you close this question by accepting the answer and asking a new question if you have any other issue.

Comment: the new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42317938/selecting-in-sqlite-database-android

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean with freeze, how did yo notice it? However, I would make the following changes

```
save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View vv) {
                    name = e1.getText().toString();
                    desc = e2.getText().toString();
                    if (!name.isEmpty() && !desc.isEmpty()){
                        InsertintoCount();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please fill in the fields!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
```

And then in `InsertingCount()` (also make sure `x` and `cDT` are initialized):

```
public void InsertintoCount(){
    String sqlc = "INSERT INTO Count VALUES('"+name+"','"+desc+"','"+x+"','"+cDT+"');";
    newdb.execSQL(sqlc);
}
```

Try it and tell us back how it went !

Comment: the app just goes not responding, i was not able to do anything. It just got freezed..!

Comment: How do I "initialise" it?? I have declared those variables when the class starts...

Comment: @AlokNaushad Use the code I provided and tell us if it worked.

Comment: It didn't work... The force closing stopped but the values doesn't get added to the Database...

Comment: @AlokNaushad That's another problem. You said the App isn't responding, and now it responds. If you want help on the inserts, post another question on stackoverflow, or edit your question with the database creation and tell us what `x` and `cDT` are. We are no magicians.