# Selecting in SQLite Database Android

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, sql-insert

Whenever I Create a new database and insert a data into it, i am able to select the inserted data but the second time I insert into the table and try to select it, it shows me the first data itself.

This is the code of the onClickListener(that selects from table):

```
mydb = openOrCreateDatabase("Countz_DB",MODE_PRIVATE,null);
```

and

```
mnew.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            c = mydb.rawQuery("Select * from Countz",null);
            if (c.moveToFirst()){
                name = c.getString(0);
                desc = c.getString(1);
                Snackbar.make(v, "Name:"+name+" Desc:"+desc, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

This is the code that I use to insert values into the table:

```
public void InsertintoCount(){
    String sqlc = "INSERT INTO Countz VALUES('"+name+"','"+desc+"','"+x+"','"+cDT+"');";
    newdb.execSQL(sqlc);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
if (c.moveToFirst()){
    do {
            name = c.getString(0);
            desc = c.getString(1);
            Snackbar.make(v, "Name:"+name+" Desc:"+desc, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } while(c.moveToNext());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because your cursor always move to the first location on the click event. Try doing the following::

```
mnew.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        c = mydb.rawQuery("Select * from Countz",null);
        if (c.moveToLast()){
            name = c.getString(0);
            desc = c.getString(1);
            Snackbar.make(v, "Name:"+name+" Desc:"+desc, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
});
```

If you want to iterate over all the rows on the table then ::

```
mnew.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        c = mydb.rawQuery("Select * from Countz",null);
        if(c>0) {
        c.moveToFirst();
        do {
            name = c.getString(0);
            desc = c.getString(1);
            Snackbar.make(v, "Name:"+name+" Desc:"+desc, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       } while(c.moveToNext());
        }
    }
});
```

You will get all posted value after that.

If you want the recently inserted value then you have to return the rowId after the insertion operation and then get the row from database using query "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id="+id;

But the better way to handle the database transactions is to create a handler class and access it from where ever you need.

Follow this tutorial ::
[SQLite Database Example](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/)

Answer (score 1):

That's because you only read the result once. `Cursor` has several rows, you have to go through them.

You have to iterate over the `Cursor`.

Try the following:

```
if (c.moveToFirst()){
    do {
            name = c.getString(0);
            desc = c.getString(1);
            Snackbar.make(v, "Name:"+name+" Desc:"+desc, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } while (c.moveToNext());
}
```

Tell us if it worked.

Comment: This will skip the first entry.

Comment: @AbhishekJain Wops, it's true. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

> the second time I insert into the table and try to select it, it shows
>   me the first data itself.

That's because you are selecting the first entry itself.

```
if (c.moveToFirst()){
    name = c.getString(0);
    desc = c.getString(1);
    Snackbar.make(v, "Name:"+name+" Desc:"+desc, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Notice [`c.moveToFirst()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#moveToFirst()). This will take you to the first entry in the cursor. If you want the last entry use [`c.moveToLast()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#moveToLast()).

OR if you want to see all the entries do something like this :

```
if (c.moveToFirst()){
    while (!c.isAfterLast) {
        name = c.getString(0);
        desc = c.getString(1);
        Snackbar.make(v, "Name:"+name+" Desc:"+desc, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        c.moveToNext();
    }
}
```

[`c.isAfterLast()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#isAfterLast()) tells whether the cursor is pointing to the position after the last row(that's the point where you want to break your loop).